# What is the proper analysis to run when trying to compare means between multiple years?

Tags: r, mean

I am trying to figure out the proper statistical analysis for my problem. I have a data set that has many variables but I am interested in how the mean deer density changes over time. I have multiple densities for each year because they are the results of a simulation that ran multiple repetitions. Below is an example of what the data looks like:

```
total-deer-density    year
35.5                     1
36.4                     1
34.8                     1
31.5                     2
32.1                     2
31.8                     2
.                        .
.                        .
.                        .
15.6                    20
15.9                    20
```

So I would want to obtain the mean "total-deer-density" for each year (year 1 to year 20) and then compare those means. Is there a statistical test that will accomplish this?

If it helps, I would say each mean is not independent. The density in year 2 depends on the density in year 1, etc.

Thank you!

Comment: Given just having two variables (density and year), one-way ANOVA can be used if you have no idea about the trend, or simple regression if you believe that density decreases along the time.

Answer (score 0):

You could come up with expected means for each year, which might be uniform, and then perform a chi-squared analysis on the means.